# How to query time between tonight and tomorrow morning shift using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

Currently, I am trying to query the time range from 20:00:00 and tomorrow morning 07:59:59. However it is taking the current date instead of tomorrow's date. This is my query:

```
Select
*                                          
FROM Test
where Name='test'
and MachineName='MTest'
and CAST (TimeStamp AS time) Between '20:00:00' and '23:59:59' or CAST (TimeStamp AS 
time) Between '00:00:00' and '07:59:59'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a date test.  This would look something like this:

```
select t.*                                          
from Test t
where t.Name = 'test' and t.MachineName = 'MTest' and
      (cast(timestamp as date) = current_date and cast(timestamp as time) >= '20:00:00' or
       cast(timestamp as date) = current_date + interval '1 day' and cast(timestamp as time) < '08:00:00'
      );
```

Note that date/time functions are notoriously dependent on the database, so the exact syntax depends on your (unspecified) database.